# why does tomcat redirect context path with slash?

Tags: tomcat, servlets

I have a servlet web app with context path "/cas" in tomcat.
When I visit "http://localhost:8080/cas", tomcat will redirect to "http://localhost:8080/cas/".
Is this behavior specified in any documents?
Is there any servlet for "/cas"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns a redirect because those are the rules specified in the Java Servlet Specification rev 3.0, in section *12.1 Use of URL Paths*. It is present (under different numbering) in all other Servlet Spec versions as well.

There is a difference between `/cas` and `/cas/`. One of them is not visible to your application (i.e. there is no `url-pattern` that you can map that will cause a resource within your web application to respond) and the other will be seen by your application as `/`.

If you map `/cas` in your `ROOT` application to something, Tomcat will ignore that because there is a longest-match rule that overrides it (the context mapped to `/cas`) so your `/cas` application will override whatever you had in your `ROOT` application mapped there.

The `/cas` request is, by definition, a directory-request without a trailing `/` and therefore Tomcat performs a redirect adding the `/`. Then section *10.10 Welcome Files* comes into play, and Tomcat will examine your application to determine what to do next.

Comment: Re "_those are the rules_", the OP is specifically asking whether the behavior is "**specified in any documents**".

Comment: @Christopher Schultz I did not found redirection thing in section "Use of URL Paths", so it is up to tomcat to redirec "/cas" to "/cas/"?

Comment: @Tim Tomcat chooses to implement the resolution from `/cas` to `/cas/` as a redirect. It could certainly handle the request internally using (what an application thinks of as) a "forward", but the redirect is a bit cleaner and gives the client a little information about what it happening.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz so it is tomcat's decision instead of Java Servlet Specification?

Comment: @Tim Yes, that's a Tomcat decision. Context-paths are treated as "directories" (even if they are not backed on on-disk directory structures) and it's common among pretty much all web servers to redirect requests to `.../dir` to `.../dir/`.